# Почему spring-data не создает bean репозитория?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

Есть простой репозиторий для объекта `Items` но при компиляции теста падает ошибка:

> [main] WARN
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext -
>   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>   refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [spring-data-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for
>   property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found

Если я правильно все понял то проблема с приведением типов для объекта `entityManagerFactory` но не понятно что к ней приводит. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Вот репозиторий:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Integer> {
}
```

Это сам объект:

```
@Entity(name = "items")
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    public Item() {
    }
    ...геттеры и сеттеры...
}
```

И конфигурационный файл `spring-data-context.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Database properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/spring_jdbc" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- Spring base scaling entity classes -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.pravvich" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionalManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="ru.pravvich" />
</beans>
```

И на всякий случай структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ругается он на это

> Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to
>   required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource';

```
<property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />
```

тут вы хотите чтобы в dataSource лежала строка "dataSource" или это отсылка к бину?

Если последние то надо так :

```
<property name="dataSource">
    <bean ref = "dataSource"/>
</property >
```

Comment: в `<property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />` я заменил `value` на `ref` совсем в прямом смысле не получилось как вы показали или я что-то не так понял, но теперь у меня другая ошибка: `oSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching PlatformTransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!`

Comment: приведите пожалуйста полный код. А то я путаюсь(((

Comment: Имя вашего бина не transactionManager, а transactionalManager